# Article url linked via 100s of comment spam - Delete the article or not?

Tags: seo, google, spam, penalty, spamming

I just noticed that someone has generated hundreds of links to one of our articles through comment spam. I wanted to know if it would be a good idea to delete this article and repost it, thereby changing the article url so the links from the comment spam will lead to a dead page (404). Also, should I also disavow these incoming comment spam links? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, according to Google. Don't Worry About Spammy Links. And you do not do anything.

John Mueller of Google was asked on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1412397449432420369) if one should disavow the spammy links that you see from an article going viral. John said "no need" to do that.